# How to load json file into Laravel Controller?

Tags: json, laravel, controller, load

I have a JSON file that I would like to load into a controller in Laravel so that I can use the data into my application.

The files path is /storage/app/calendar_Ids.json.

What is the correct way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here, this should help you get sorted.

```
use Storage;

$json = Storage::disk('local')->get('calendar_Ids.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Just saw your edit at the bottom, this worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$path = '/storage/app/calendar_Ids.json';
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);`
```

Then just `dd($content);` to see if it works.

Comment: This worked for me but do you know if there is a specific way to do it using Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```html
 $json = file_get_contents('your json file path here.....');

//converting json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data as $item){

   
        DB::table('table name')->insert(
            array(
                    
                   'clientId'     =>   $item['clientId'], 
                   'socialMediaLinkId'   =>   $item['socialMediaLinkId'],
                   'link'   =>   $item['link'],
                   'isEnabled'   =>   $item['isEnabled'],
                   'created_at'   =>   $item['created_at'],
                   'updated_at'   =>   $item['updated_at'],
                   'isSelectedByDefault'   =>$item['isSelectedByDefault'],
                   'showOnNegativePage'   =>$item['showOnNegativePage']
        
        
            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this too:

```
$json = storage_path('folder/filename.json');
```

Comment: This just generates a fully qualified path to a given file within the resources directory. Not reading file contents.